# Discord.py how to make a notifier using on_guild_update

Tags: discord.py

I saw the api docs and have no idea about how to make a guild update notifier like if i change my server's icon/logo/banner my bot should send a message in a particular channel that icon/logo/banner has been changed by{user}

so how do i make it?

Answer (score 0):

See `on_guild_update` returns 2 thing , 1st before and 2nd after , so you can use them for making log in channel

so u can add a if statement which will be checking if the old and new things are same or not if not it will post the msg like `###### is changed`